# How to push to a newly created project in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, push

I have created a new namespace and project in `gitlab` from the terminal with the command

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/nameSpace/projectName
```

but when I try to push it with the command

```
push -u origin master
```

I get the error

```
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://gitlab.com/nameSpace/projectName/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in
```

I tried also the option `--set-upstream` as suggested in gitlab documentation but it did not solve.

The project and master branch should have been created because when I try to `remote add` it tells me origin-master already exists. However using the browser I cannot see any project folder.

Many of the questions on SO were solved by adding `-u` but it did not work in my case.

How to push files to a newly created project in gitlab?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try ssh authentication:

1. Replace https origin url to ssh by:

   ```
   git remote rm origin
   git remote add origin <ssh-path-for-your-project>
   ```
2. Generate ssh key for your system by `ssh-keygen`
3. Add the generated ssh key to your profile from gitlab portal
4. Try to push now

Comment: does it work even if it is a new repo (not existing yet) or should I create first the repository via browser?

Comment: yes...you have to first create the repository via browser. After that you will have ssh-path for the repository.

Comment: So it is no possible to create it from the terminal is it?

Comment: It is possible. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you are not logged in (as it is redirecting you to signin). You should try the same command by providing your credentials.

As per [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project), you could do the following to create a project (within namespace) as follows,

```
## Git push using SSH
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master

## Git push using HTTPS
git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
```

The documentation doesn't mention about adding 'origin'. So may be you should remove that and try it.